Debian 12 Network Bridging Issue
I had set up bridged networking in the past on my desktop for VMs to obtain IPs from my home router instead of using NAT, it broke somehow a long time ago and I wanted to get it working again, so I did a fresh reinstall of the latest Debian 12 and tried bridge-utils and edited /etc/network/interfaces after creating a backup of the default configuration, to no avail. Also I tried network manager and using nmcli and nmtui to create a bridge network and this had issues as well. I'm not quite sure where I'm going wrong.
Using bridge-utils and the /etc/network/interfaces file to create a bridge proved to be very easy in the past, here's my current /etc/network/interfaces file:
#loopback if
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

#primary if
iface enp9s0 inet manual

#secondary br0 if
auto br0
iface br0 inet static
        address 192.168.1.133/24
        gateway 192.168.1.1
        bridge-ports enp9s0
        bridge-stp off
        bridge-fd 0


Here enp9s0 is my primary ethernet device and br0 is the bridge device. The problem is when it does get applied, it works and I have connection, until i specify in a virtmanager VM to use a bridge device called br0, and once the VM is started,it cuts the internet out on the host machine completely.
